# Python TimeSeries Error: ValueError: view limit minimum -36834.64916714945 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value

Tags: python

I'm creating a time series model in Python. I converted a int field that counted the days (1,2,3,4) to a datetime field using the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime.strptime('2016-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')

df['Day'] = [start + timedelta(x) for x in range(730)]
```

I checked and it worked. The first date starts with 01/01/2016. I checked the dtypes of my two columns. The Day column is a datetime64[ns], while the revenue columns is float64.

When I try to plot the following code, I get an error that says I'm receiving this error: ValueError: view limit minimum -36834.64916714945 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units. I'm a little confused as to what's causing this since my datatype on the day columns is a datetime.

```
rolling_mean = df.rolling(window = 12).mean()
rolling_std = df.rolling(window = 12).std()
plt.plot(df, color = 'blue', label = 'Original')
plt.plot(rolling_mean, color = 'red', label = 'Rolling Mean')
plt.plot(rolling_std, color = 'black', label = 'Rolling Std')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.title('Rolling Mean & Rolling Standard Deviation')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: We'll need some sample data, and full traceback to which line the error occurs

Answer (score 2):

I assume an arbitrary `df` like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(720, 3), columns=list('abc'))
```

`pyplot.plot([...])` [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) expects a `x` and `y`, but you didn't specify what the `x` should be. If we include `x` as datetime values and `y` as the desired `mean` or `std` values, then the code looks like:

```py
start = datetime.strptime('2016-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')

df['day'] = [start + timedelta(x) for x in range(720)]

rolling_mean = df.rolling(window = 12, on="day").mean()
rolling_std = df.rolling(window = 12, on="day").std()

colors=['olive', 'gold', 'green', 'red', 'black', 'blue', 'purple', 'coral', 'teal']
for idx in df.columns.drop('day'):
    plt.plot(df['day'], df[idx], color = np.random.choice(colors), label = 'Original')
    plt.plot(rolling_mean['day'], rolling_mean[idx], color = np.random.choice(colors), label = 'Rolling Mean ' + str(idx))
    plt.plot(rolling_std['day'], rolling_std[idx], color = np.random.choice(colors), label = 'Rolling Std ' + str(idx))
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.title('Rolling Mean & Rolling Standard Deviation')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

This will give you this rainbow-coloured plot (if you wish other colors, check [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html))

[image]